# How to specify strongly typed navigational property includes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, include

I am writing a EF repository and one of my functions allows you to find a particular object by a predicate whilst specifying includes

```
IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, 
                     params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
```

This works great, however one of the includes I want to specify is a navigational property of a navigational property.

My call currently looks like this which would be `"Folders.Devices"` if specified as a string.

```
var folder = _Folders.FindBy(f => f.FolderId == id, f => f.Devices).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I were to specify this extra navigational property by string it would be

```
"Folders.Devices.Nodes"
```

My question is how do I include the `Nodes` property of each `Device` within `Devices` in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var folder = _Folders.FindBy(f => f.FolderId == id, f => f.Devices.SelectMany(x=>x.Nodes)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite right but pointed me in the right direction.  I had to use `f => f.Devices.Select(d => d.Nodes)`

Comment: @Chris isn't your `Nodes` a collection? if so your query would return a collection of collection? I didn't think that's what you want, I just thought you wanted a collection passed in as the second argument.

Comment: It is, but when I tried your code it threw an exception and told me to use `Select` after which it worked!